# For each loop behaving irrationally - R

Tags: r, loops

I want to use the foreach function and the %dopar% function to parallelise some analysis I want to run. However, I run into the problem that the foreach loop is behaving irrationally. For example, when I ask it to return 10 iterations, it gives me any number of iterations (but not 10). Weirdly enough, asking for 1,2,3 iterations works fine. Moreover, the loops are not being counted. I created a reproducible example below. The expected output I want is a dataset with 20 rows and a count variable corresponding to the number of iterations. The output I got was a dataset with 64 rows with seemingly arbitrary numbers between 1-5.

Clarification:
I´m fine any sort of unique identifier that identifies a unique run.

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(here, ez, tidyverse, ggpubr, rstatix, plyr, gtools, ggplot2, reshape2, ggthemes, doParallel, foreach)

#set up backend
registerDoParallel(cores=4)

#I want 20 iterations
permutation <- 1:20
#an empty dataframe
df_test <- data.frame()

#initialise count to 0
count <- 0
#measure speed
system.time({
  dataframe <- foreach(permutation, .combine = rbind) %dopar% { #What I want it do is, to run n = permutation iterations of whatever I put in the brackets. 
    
    #save the dataset
    count <-  count + 1 
    df_test <- as.data.frame(cbind(rbind(df_test, count)))
    
  }
  
  
})
```

Comment: So you want each iteration to use the data from the one before, but you also want this to be done in parallel?

Comment: Imagine you run 500 tests on 4 cores, so 125 per core. What I want is that there is a unique identifier for each of the 500 tests. In for loops you can do this by using count + 1, hence I tried to use it here, too. Do you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is that there is a unique identifier for each of the 500 tests.

That cannot be done within all the different parallel threads, this needs to be done in the one thread to rule them all. Luckily, `foreach` handles that for you in the background:

```
#set up backend
registerDoParallel(cores=4)

#I want 20 iterations
permutation <- 1:20

#measure speed
system.time({
  dataframe <- foreach(i = permutation, .combine = rbind) %dopar% { 
    this.result <- rnorm(1)
    return(paste0("This is the ", i, "nt random number: ", this.result))
  }
})

print(dataframe)
```

will yield

```
> print(dataframe)
          [,1]                                                 
result.1  "This is the 1nt random number: -0.192831515547914"  
result.2  "This is the 2nt random number: 0.423554282920886"   
result.3  "This is the 3nt random number: -1.6001206841383"    
result.4  "This is the 4nt random number: 0.138173481473908"   
result.5  "This is the 5nt random number: -0.661101542161897"  
result.6  "This is the 6nt random number: 1.784573622211"      
result.7  "This is the 7nt random number: -1.7073627467627"    
result.8  "This is the 8nt random number: 2.18051375137318"    
result.9  "This is the 9nt random number: -1.73210460300292"   
result.10 "This is the 10nt random number: 0.575991214184181"  
result.11 "This is the 11nt random number: 0.0600232989879976" 
result.12 "This is the 12nt random number: 1.38835345865588"   
result.13 "This is the 13nt random number: -0.184044116272533" 
result.14 "This is the 14nt random number: -0.153445402386569" 
result.15 "This is the 15nt random number: 0.657291633776239"  
result.16 "This is the 16nt random number: -0.0304732914484288"
result.17 "This is the 17nt random number: -0.614497653887793" 
result.18 "This is the 18nt random number: 0.399615511946809"  
result.19 "This is the 19nt random number: -0.382140906398317" 
result.20 "This is the 20nt random number: -0.774233327172599"
```

As you can see, `foreach` made nice row names as identifiers for the results and I could use `i` within each thread to refer to the correct identifying number as well.

`foreach` does that and a lot more for you but some work can easily be parallelized and some not. You must think about parallelism nevertheless. When doing thinks in parallel, you never know which thread will start or finish first or last and in which order they will try to read or set `count`. If they all stood in line to do it in the correct order, the advantages of parallelism could quickly disappear.

There is a good introduction by Florian Privé in which he writes

> A common mistake is to think that foreach is like a for-loop. Actually, foreach is more like lapply.

cf. https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/

Comment: `foreach` parallel will break down the loop evenly into multiple small batches then run loop through each batch parallel. Ideally when using `forech` consider each loop is completely independent from each others. If you need to communicate across threads, using one file or multiple files that can be create/remove/read/write parallel could also help.